# mkoctfile with multiple C and C++ source files

Tags: c++, c, compilation, linker, octave

I am not able to have `mkoctfile` to successfully create an `oct` file that is a wrapper of some `C++` function of mine (e.g. `void my_fun(double*,double)`). In particular my problem rises from the fact that, the wrapper code `my_fun_wrap.cpp` requires the inclusion of the `<octave/oct.h>` library which only provides `C++` headers (see [here](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/mkoctfile-and-C-td3317051.html)), but the original code of `my_fun` also uses source code that is in `C`. E.g.

```
// my_fun_wrapper.cpp

#include <octave/oct.h>
#include "custom_functions_libc.h"

DEFUN_DLD(my_fun_wrapper,args, , "EI MF network model A with delays (Brunel, JCN 2000)"){

// Input arguments
NDArray xvar = args(0).array_value();
double x = xvar(0);

// Output arguments
double dy[4];
dim_vector dv (4,1);
NDArray dxvars(dv);

// Invoke my C function which also includes code in the lib file custom_functions_libc.c  
my_fun(dy,x);

// Then assign output value to NDArray
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) dxvars(i) = dy[i];

// Cast output as octave_value as required by the octave guidelines
return octave_value (dxvars);
}
```

Then suppose that my `custom_functions_libc.h` and `custom_functions_libc.c` files are somewhere in a folder `<path_to_folder>/my_libs`. Ideally, from Octave command line I would compile the above by:

```
mkoctfile -g -v -O -I<path_to_folder>/my_libs <path_to_folder>/my_libs/custom_functions_libc.c my_fun_wrapper.cpp -output my_fun_wrapper -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

This actually generates `my_fun_wrapper.oct` as required. Then I can call this latter from within some `octave` code, e.g.

```
...
... 
xx = [0., 2.5, 1.];
yy = [1e-5, 0.1, 2.];    

dxv = test_my_function(xx,yy);


function dy = test_my_function(xx,yy)
    xx += yy**2;
    dy = my_fun_wrapper(xx);        
endfunction
```

It turns out that the above code will exit with an error in `test_my_function` saying that within the `my_fun_wrapper` the symbol `Zmy_fundd` is not recognized. Upon receiving such kind of error I suspected that something went wrong on the linking process. But strangely enough the compiler did not produce any error as I said. Yet, a closer inspection of the verbose output of the compiler revealed that `mkoctfile` is changing compiler automatically between different files depending on their extension. So `my_fun_wrapper.cpp` is compiled by `g++ -std=gnu++11` but `custom_function_libc.c` is compiled by `gcc -std=gnu11` and somehow the `custom_function_libc.o` file ensuing by this compilation process, when linked with `my_fun_wrapper.o` does not matches unresolved symbols.

The example above is very simplistic. In practice, in my case `custom_function_libc` includes many more custom `C` libraries. A workaround so far was to clone the `.c` source file for those libraries into `.cpp` files. But I do not like this solution very much.

How can I eventually mix `C++` and `C` code safely and compile it successfully by `mkoctfile`? `octave` manual suggests to prepend an `extern C` specification (see [here](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Calling-External-Code-from-Oct_002dFiles.html)) which I am afraid I am not very familiar with. Is this the best way? Could you suggest me alternatively, a potential alternative solution?

Comment: Since you doesn't provide enough code to compile this or a minimal example it's not "verifiable", see link in Cris's comment. So my debug tip is: strip down your code so that ei_modelA only uses some trivial caluclation and remove all the cruft around...

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes sorry about it. The code is not easily protable. Let me please follow Andy's advice first and break it down to small pieces and see if I can identify the problem. If not I will attempt to improve the post. On the other hand if successful I will elaborate my post in a better fashion. Thanks for your patience (currently on GMT+1).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I figured out where the linking issue rose. Now I rephrased my question hopefully in a more clear fashion

Comment: @Andy Thanks. I managed to backtrace the issue by your suggestion. Now hopefully either you or Chris can provide me with more insights.

Comment: Where is `Zdy_fundd` defined? Is it in one of the `-lgsl -lgslcblas` libs? In general, if you don't get linker warnings, the linker found all required functions. But if you are linking to a shared object (dynamic library) then it is possible that the library is not found *at runtime*, so you get the errors then. Is this Linux? Linking is different on every platform, so it is a good idea to add that info to your question.

Comment: Also, yes, maybe you need to do `extern "C" {` \n `#include "custom_functions_libc.h"` \n `}`. (trying to show line breaks with "\n")

Comment: Does `custom_functions_libc.h` define a function `my_fun`, that is being mangled by the C++ compiler to `Zmy_fundd`? If so, adding `extern "C"` should fix the problem.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes sorry. I mistyped it (now corrected). No no it is not a GSL function. The reason I am linking the GSL library is because inside my `C` code I am using GSL functions indeed. Anyhow, the `extern C` trick indeed seems the right solution. I recompiled as a try and seems to work. I am going to post a reply for this. Yet, this fact that `mkoctfile` does not issue any error and still compiles yet using different compilers based on different file extensions was a tricky one

Comment: So the main problem is, that you are linking C code (compiled with gcc) and C++ code (compiled with g++) which gives you problems with name mangling (google it!). Nothing related to GNU Octave

Answer (score 2):

So apparently the easiest solution, according to my above post is to correct the wrapper by the following preprocessor directives:

```
// my_fun_wrapper.cpp

#include <octave/oct.h>

// ADDED code to include the C source code
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
// END ADDITION
#include "custom_functions_libc.h"
// ADDED code to include the C source code
#ifdef __cplusplus
}  /* end extern "C" */
#endif
// END ADDITION

...
...
```

This will compile and link fine.

Comment: Since your wrapper is C++ code, you don't need the `#ifdef` in there. It will always be compiled with a C++ compiler. If you put the `extern "C"` command in the C header file, then you need to add those `#ifdef`s, then the header file is compatible with both a C compiler and a C++ compiler.